# css justify button horizontally and text below icons

Tags: html, css, list, font-awesome

I am trying to put my text just below the font awesome icon and i would like to make my two buttons be of centered on the page of equal distance from each other.currently the icon is showing just next to the text and the buttons are one after another .

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li><a class="btn btn-warning btn-outline btn-lg sharp" href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> My text below icon <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i></a>

</li>
  <li><a class="btn btn-info btn-lg sharp" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">My text below icon  <i class="fa fa-address-book fa-5x"></i></a></li>

</ul>
```

and here is my css bit:

```
ul#mylist li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just make `display: block;` for font-awesome icon:

```css
ul#mylist li {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 10%;
}
ul#mylist li i {
    display: block;
}

ul#mylist li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
ul#mylist li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="mylist" class="text-center">
  <li><a class="btn btn-warning btn-outline btn-lg sharp" href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>My text below icon</a>

</li>
  <li><a class="btn btn-info btn-lg sharp" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-address-book fa-5x"></i>My text below icon  </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you edit your code just as a minute ago when the icons were far apart?

Comment: i've changed answer. pls